# How to create an image with transparency

Tags: python

I have a script to create an image but i want it to be created with transparency:

```
import bpy

bpy.data.images.new("albedo", width=1024, height=1024)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are actually asking:

- If you need ot create an **RGBA** image, so an image that also has the Alpha Channel. (So a RGBA type instead of the normal RGB). Just Check ALPHA when you create it via UI or in code:

  `bpy.data.images.new("albedo", width=1024, height=1024, alpha = True)`
- If you want the default color to be instead of black any other color so even one with some transparency, this is the fastest way I found:

  `im = bpy.data.images.new("albedo", width=1024, height=1024, alpha = True)
  im.generated_color = (1,0,0,0.5)`

This code actually generates a Red image half transparent.